# Porque al ponerle position: fixed al header el contenido que esta abajo se esconde abajo del header

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de dejar el `<header>` fijo, y que cuando se deslice, este no se esconda.

Para esto, utilizo `position: fixed`, pero cuando hago esto, el contenido de la web se esconde abajo del `<header>`.

> O sea es como que eliminaras el `<header>` y los demás contenidos tomaran ese lugar.

```css
*{
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
 .head{
     background: red;
     height: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 999;
     right: 0;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
}
 img{
     height: 40px;
     margin-top: 5px;
}

 #pie{
     display: flex;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     height: 120px;
     background: green;
     width: 100%;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}

 #servidores{
     display: grid;
     background: purple;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="head"></div>
</header>
<section id="servidores">
  <p>bienvenido a xnovawop. haga click para iniciar</p>
  <button>Iniciar</button>
</section>
```

> Resumen: **El `position: fixed` me afecta el contenido de la web completa**, ¿cómo puedo solucionar este problema? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuando pones la propiedad `position: fixed` esta saca tu componente del layout por lo que siempre se va a superponer, la solución es poner un `padding-top`/ `margin-top` que ocupe el espacio vacio.
sin embargo la mejor solución es usar `position: sticky` con un `top: 0` ya que este se integra en el layout y una vez se hace scroll sale y se mantiene en pantalla en este caso con top en la parte superior.

te dejo un snippet para que lo puedas observar
**modifique un poco tu código original para lograrlo

```css
*{
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
header{
     background: red;
     height: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     position: sticky; //cambiamos la propiedad a una adecuada
     z-index: 999;
     top: 0;
}
 img{
     height: 40px;
     margin-top: 5px;
}

 #pie{
     display: flex;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     height: 120px;
     background: green;
     width: 100%;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}

 #servidores{
     display: grid;
     background-color: purple;
     height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="head"></div>
</header>
<section id="servidores">
  <p>bienvenido a xnovawop. haga click para iniciar</p>
  <button>Iniciar</button>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

El truco está en aumentar el padding superior (top) del contenido para separar la cabecera y el contenido.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.head {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#pie {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 120px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#servidores {
  display: grid;
  background: purple;
  padding-top: 50px;
  /* el mismo valor que la altura del head */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>
  <header>
    <div class="head"></div>
  </header>

  <section id="servidores">
    <p>bienvenido a xnovawop. haga click para iniciar</p>
    <button>iniciar</button>
  </section>
  <br/>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. Nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet. Ut placerat
    orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim. Lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Felis eget nunc lobortis mattis. Turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est. Tempor id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus.
    Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque. Libero nunc consequat interdum varius. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at. Ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat. Ac felis donec
    et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed. A condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. At elementum eu facilisis sed odio. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam
    sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo. Orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor. Augue eget arcu dictum varius. Pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh
    nisl. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat. Dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique. Adipiscing elit ut aliquam
    purus sit amet luctus venenatis. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Pretium lectus quam id leo in. Aenean et
    tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at. Massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est. Eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac. Purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl
    suscipit adipiscing. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Proin sagittis nisl rhoncus
    mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra. Consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend. Lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus. Lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget.
    Amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius. Posuere sollicitudin
    aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi. Amet justo donec enim diam. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat
    semper viverra nam. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed augue. Id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam non. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl
    suscipit adipiscing bibendum. Pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi. Auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in. Et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer. Eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing. Faucibus nisl
    tincidunt eget nullam non nisi. Amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan. Adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum
    posuere. Quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin sed libero. Faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris.</p>

</body>

</html>
```